# Error while executing Hive command line

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hadoop-plugins

I am getting the following error when tried to execute hive command line interface. May I know the incompatible Jar files causing the problem and the solution to fix it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFJSONTuple.<clinit>(GenericUDTFJSONTuple.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerGenericUDTF(FunctionRegistry.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerGenericUDTF(FunctionRegistry.java:539)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.<clinit>(FunctionRegistry.java:472)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:613)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Comment: Followed the tutorial https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-Requirements.   Let me know if there is any alternate tutorial for installation of Hive better than this?

Comment: What is the query that you are trying to execute? I wonder if this exception indicates that you are trying to use some UDF that you are missing.

Comment: I am getting the error, while starting hive from command line itself..

Comment: Found the solution : Incompatible jackson files in hadoop and hive

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/swing-heil/source/browse/trunk/andoird/test+project/DaumNaverTwitterOAuth/src/NaverOAuthBasicExample.java?spec=svn48&r=48